# It doesn't add an edges with the right in and out vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I'd like to add a new edge between two vertices.

Here is the command I'm using

```
def graph=ConfiguredGraphFactory.open('graph');
def g = graph.traversal();

graph.addVertex(label, 'Person', 'name', 'Jack', 'entityId', '100');
graph.addVertex(label, 'Person', 'name', 'John', 'entityId', '50');

def v1 = g.V().has('entityId', '100').next();
def v2 = g.V().has('entityId', '50').next();
v1.addEdge('managerOf',v2,'inEntityId', '100', 'outEntityId', '50')
```

Then whenever I want to get the path I just created:

```
g.V().outE().inV().path();
```

It returns:

```
[
  {
    "labels": [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ],
    "objects": [
      {
        "id": 40968272,
        "label": "Person",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "name": [
            {
              "id": "oe22y-oe3bk-6mmd",
              "value": "Jack"
            }
          ],
          "entityId": [
            {
              "id": "oe2h6-oe3bk-6ozp",
              "value": "100"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "1crua2-oe3bk-4is5-oectk",
        "label": "managerOf",
        "type": "edge",
        "inVLabel": "Person",
        "outVLabel": "Person",
        "inV": 40980584,
        "outV": 40968272,
        "properties": {
          "outEntityId": "50",
          "inEntityId": "100"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 40980584,
        "label": "Person",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "name": [
            {
              "id": "1cs5ql-oectk-6mmd",
              "value": "John"
            }
          ],
          "entityId": [
            {
              "id": "1cs64t-oectk-6ozp",
              "value": "50"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice that the edge doesn't reflect what I just created. It's inverted! How is it possible? Am I doing anything wrong?

I'm using JanusGraph, in the data browser it also displays the edge with the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's right. You reversed your properties though on your edge. the "outEntityId" should be "100" (Jack) and the "inEntityId" should be "50" (John) just as the edge is `inV` and `outV` reflects. To say it another way, you created

```
jack-managerOf->john
```

for that "managerOf" edge, the edge goes out of "jack", thus the `outV` is "jack", and goes into "john", thus the `inV` is "john".

Note that you can simplify your vertex/edge addition by going the recommended route of using the Traversal API (aka Gremlin):

```
gremlin> g.addV('Person').property('name', 'Jack').property('entityId', '100').as('jack').
......1>   addV('Person').property('name', 'John').property('entityId', '50').as('john').
......2>   addE('managerOf').from('jack').to('john').property('inEntityId', '50').property('outEntityId', '100').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().outE().inV().path().by('name').by(valueMap())
==>[Jack,[inEntityId:50,outEntityId:100],John]
```